# Android: how to play an mp3(URL) file using the any of the installed apps

Tags: android

I have URL poins to mp3 file

what I need is when the user click a certain button in my layout I want the android OS to display a list of the installed apps that can handle this URL

can this done or I should use the MediaPlayer class?

Answer (score 0):

To open a url, android system will show browsers list. But i think you need apps which can stream music. I dont think there is any system app that can do it. or else you can download music when user clicks on button and then open music players by media intent or mediaplayer class.

Comment: I noticed that when I pass the mp3 URL to the browser it open small window containing seek bar and play/pause button and then the mp3 file starts playing ... can I talk directly to that player or I must go through the browser (the browser is the default android 4.0 browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("your song.mp3");
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileStream.getFD());
```

Try this